# Java - object existence dilem

Tags: java, arrays, object

I wrote the following, this is a toString of a Country class that has City class in same package, and _cities is an array represents the cities within my Country:
*****EDITED:*****

```
public String toString(){

    String allCitiesData = "";   //must be initialized 

    for(int i=0;this._cities[i] != null;i++)//run all over the cities until reach the end(null cell)
    {   //concat new city to the string and adds a new line between
        allCitiesData = allCitiesData.concat(this._cities[i].toString()+"\n\n");
    }
    return allCitiesData;
}//toString method  

public String citiesNorthOf(String cityName){
    String allCitiesNorthOf = "";// must be initialized

    for(int i=0; this._cities[i] != null ; i++)
    {
        if (this._cities[i].getCityName() == cityName)
        {
            Point referenceCityCenter = new Point(this._cities[i].getCityCenter());
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; this._cities[i] != null ; i++)//we don't need to exclude the comparable city itself because it will give a false
    {
        if (this._cities[i].getCityCenter().isAbove(referenceCityCenter)) 
        {
            allCitiesNorthOf = allCitiesNorthOf.concat(this._cities[i].toString()+"\n\n");
        }
    }
}//citiesNorthOf method
```

But, when I run it, it shows a single error only on this line:

```
if (this._cities[i].getCityCenter().isAbove(referenceCityCenter))
```

And the Eclipse says: "referenceCityCenter cannot be resolved to a variable".. any suggestions ?

Thanks !!

Comment: `referenceCityCenterr` vs `referenceCityCenter`. Read up on variable scope.

Comment: Also want to remove "Point" in the if statement if you are trying to assign the value to that variable.

Comment: I edit the question... now there's other problem instead... plz read.. thx !

Comment: Assuming you've corrected the misspelling causing your original error, you need to change the name of one of the variables named `referenceCityCenter`. The error message is pretty clear: you can't declare two variables named the same thing in a method. How would it know which one you're talking about?

Comment: Now that you've changed the question again, refer to @SotiriosDelimanolis : "Read up on variable scope."

Comment: Now I fixed everything and the problem is really as described with the new real errors... can you show me an alternative way to handle this problem according to my constraints ?thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`referenceCityCenter` is out of scope. Put it outside of your `if` statement and make sure you check for `null` afterwards like follows:

```
public String citiesNorthOf(String cityName){
String allCitiesNorthOf = "";// must be initialized

Point referenceCityCenter = null;

for(int i=0; this._cities[i] != null ; i++)
{
    if (this._cities[i].getCityName() == cityName)
    {
        referenceCityCenter = new Point(this._cities[i].getCityCenter());
    }
}

for(int i=0; this._cities[i] != null ; i++)//we don't need to exclude the comparable city itself because it will give a false
{
    if (referenceCityCenter !- null && this._cities[i].getCityCenter().isAbove(referenceCityCenter)) 
    {
        allCitiesNorthOf = allCitiesNorthOf.concat(this._cities[i].toString()+"\n\n");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `referenceCityCenter` in a scope which is not visible to that line of your code.  Try declaring it at the beginning of the method (and control too if it is `null` when it arrives to your validation `.isAbove()`! :P )

Comment: Yasmani fixed it! :)  Just make sure you control the null value for when they ask you for a city name you don't know in your array